# Default python path - bash: /usr/local/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory

Tags: kubuntu, python, python3, paths, python-2.7

When I write `python` on **terminal** get an error

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
```

but if I use in terminal `python2` or `python3` it's working perfectly

How to solve this?
Please help me

Comment: It seems that symlink is meesed up. What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have symbolic link for python.

1. If you want to use python3 when you type python run the following command:

```bsh
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

2. If you want to use python2 when you type python run the following command:

```bsh
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
```

If you encounter below problem 
`ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python': File exists`,
try deleting the symbolic link for python using `sudo rm /usr/bin/python`
and try above solution.

I hope it helps.